# How to plot polynom coefficients and new result in the figure in python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, polynomials

I have following code which is pretty simple measurement set for an amplifier.
What i am ploting is the transfer curve of the amplifier output power vs gain. What i am doint next is i use the numpy package to let python calculate a polynom of 9th order which could describe my measurement data as best as possible.

The idea is when i have the polynom i could calculate for any output power level which i wish what value of gain could be expected.

So i get the coefficients and print them out and make a test run for desired output power of 52dBm what would be the gain and then print it out.

My problems are two:

1. i want this calculated Gain value also to be plotted in the same figure so i could see it in the graph compared to the polynomial curve which is already plotted / fitted to the measured points.

this is solved. I added following plot code: `plt.plot(52, test, marker = 'P', markersize=7 )`

2. i would have the coefficients also plotted as a polynom in the legend of the figure like y = c8*x8^8 + c7*x7^7 + ... + c0.

I would be thankfull if someone could give me a hand. I attach also an image what exactly i have in mind.
[image]

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import interpolate
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import style

out_pwr_m = np.array([46.95, 48.30, 49.96, 51.74, 53.03, 53.96, 54.85, 55.43, 56.00, 56.51, 56.97, 57.41, 57.80, 58.13, 58.20, 58.27, 58.32, 58.39, 58.47])
gain_m = np.array([74.55, 75.3, 75.66, 76.34, 76.73, 76.96, 77.15, 77.23, 77.3, 77.31, 77.27, 77.11, 76.8, 76.33, 76.196, 75.974, 75.818, 75.593, 75.365])

out_pwr_p = np.linspace(40, 60, 100)

p3 = np.polyfit(out_pwr_m, gain_m, 9)

gain_p = np.polyval(p3, out_pwr_p)

test = np.polyval(p3, 52)

style.use("bmh")

ticks_x = np.arange(46, 60, 0.6)
ticks_y = np.arange(74, 78, 0.25)

plt.figure(figsize=(10,6), dpi=250)
plt.xticks(ticks_x)
plt.yticks(ticks_y)

plt.plot(out_pwr_m, gain_m, 'Dr' )
plt.plot(out_pwr_p, gain_p, color = 'y', linestyle = '--')
plt.plot(test, '*')

plt.legend(['Daten', 'Polynomkurve 9-ter Ordnung'], loc = 'best')
plt.ylim(74, 78)
plt.xlim(46,59)

plt.xlabel("Output Power @ flange [dBm]", fontweight ='bold', size=11)
plt.ylabel("Gain [dB]", fontweight ='bold', size=11)

plt.annotate('y ={:.7g} x\xB8 + {:.7g} x\xB7 + {:.7g} x\xB6 + {:.7g} x\xB5 + {:.7g} x\xB4 + {:.7g} x\xB3 + {:.7g} x\xB2 + {:.7g} x + {:.7g}'.format(*p3))

print("P3 : \n", p3)

print(test)
```

Answer (score 0):

Adapted from the answer by [@SylvainD](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/9452/sylvaind) from [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/54646/string-representation-of-a-polynomial) post, if you define the auxiliary function

```
def poly(p, var_string='x'):
    res = ''
    first_pow = len(p) - 1
    for i, coef in enumerate(p):
        power = first_pow - i

        if coef:
            if coef < 0:
                sign, coef = (' - ' if res else '- '), -coef
            elif coef > 0: # must be true
                sign = (' + ' if res else '')

            str_coef = '' if coef == 1 and power != 0 else str('{:2.2f}'.format(coef))

            if power == 0:
                str_power = ''
            elif power == 1:
                str_power = var_string
            else:
                str_power = var_string + '^' + str(power)

            res += sign + str_coef + str_power 
    return res
```

then

`print(p3)` would give you a string representation of the polynomial. You can adjust the accuracy of the coefficients by manipulating the `:2.2f` in the function.

Comment: i guess when i pass my result from p3 into the new defined poly function the print function should look like : `- 0.00x^9 + 0.00x^8 - 0.00x^7 + 0.23x^6 - 4.60x^5 - 473.96x^4 + 41811.06x^3 - 1511465.11x^2 + 27357332.93x - 203534080.72` ?

Answer (score 0):

I kind of found out that one can use LaTEX to make the annotations / text look better and used it in my code like this:

`plt.annotate(r'$y ={:.7g} * x^9 + {:.7g} * x^8 + {:.7g} * x^7 + {:.7g} * x^6 + {:.7g} * x^5 + {:.7g} * x^4 + {:.7g} * x^3 + {:.7g} * x^2 + {:.7g} * x + {:.7g}$'.format(*p3), xy=(46.5, 77.50))`

i also needed to increase the size of the plot in order to be able to plot everything inside:
`plt.figure(figsize=(16,10), dpi=250)`

The result looks not that bad. Definetely a step i the right direction. Still i would like to break the polynomial equation in the annotation in multiple lines in order to not be forced to increase the size of the whole plot...[image]